# Django: Accessing reusable app in settings.py

Tags: python, django

I have a reusable django app installed in my project, and the desired outcome is to import it into the main project's settings.py.
The project runs well with the reusable app installed and added into  INSTALLED APPS in settings.py.
However, when I try to import it in settings.py, django throws an error.

```
#import statement
from config_table.models import *

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     ..., #other apps
    'config_table', #reusable app
     ... #other apps

]
```

Error Traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\repo\Auth\auth\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\repo\Auth\auth\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\repo\Auth\auth\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\repo\Auth\auth\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 386, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\repo\Auth\auth\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 87, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\repo\Auth\auth\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 74, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\repo\Auth\auth\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\repo\Auth\auth\auth\settings.py", line 52, in <module>
    from config_table.models import *
  File "C:\Users\repo\Auth\auth\venv\lib\site-packages\config_table\models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "C:\Users\repo\Auth\auth\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\repo\Auth\auth\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\repo\Auth\auth\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 127, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\repo\Auth\auth\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\repo\Auth\auth\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 138, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I think it has something to do with Django not loading the reusable app in time before the imports, but I'm not sure how to solve this.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: You should include the code and exact error.

Comment: @SivaSankar added the code and error

Comment: First of all its wrong approach to import app models like this from config_table.models import *. Django is not ready in reading all apps while running the server. Why do you want to do this and what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to use a reusable app to store configuration values, then calling those values in settings.py. Just trying it out if its possible